# alert containing value on submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I got this code in java script and I need to print the user name and password and address after submit or on submit as alert

```
    function green()
    {
        document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = "<form name='f1' onsubmit='alert(un.value)>Enter name:<input name='un' type=text  /> <br/> Enter Password: <input type=password name='ps' /> <input type='hidden' value='"+interval +"' name='in' /> <br/> <a onclick='address()'>address</a> <br/> <input type=submit value=ok /> </form>";

    }

<div id="box" style="width:380px;height:400px" />   
    <td width="95" align="center"><a onclick="green()">green</a></td>
```

code and one help me ... cause I'm not so good in javascript

Comment: Try adding the vents _in JavaScript_, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: is green in script tags?

Comment: Your `onsubmit='alert(un.value)'` is missing a close single quote.